# "Trusted hosts pattern"-error during installation of TYPO3 6.2

Tags: php, installation, typo3, global, typo3-6.2.x

I am trying to install the new version of TYPO3 6.2 LTS on a new domain. When I am done installing I want to merge the website onto this new domain. The current version of TYPO3 that the website is using is 4.5 LTS.

This is the tutorial video I used provided by my host: http://www.infomaniak.com/en/support/faq/948

I followed each step and until the install tool. Once I finished that, an error message appears.
In the tutorial video the install tool starts at 4:20 and around minute 4:58 you see, that to finish the installation you would click on "open the backend" and you can log in to the TYPO3 backend (that's how close I am to finishing!). Instead, when I clicked on "open the backend" I got an error about the trusted hosts pattern.

Here's the error:

**Oops, an error occurred!**

**The current host header value does not match the configured trusted hosts pattern! Check the pattern defined in $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['trustedHostsPattern'] and adapt it, if you want to allow the current host header 'bzhs.ch' for your installation.**

Can anyone help me? I think I should find someplace to change the **$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['trustedHostsPattern']** and there is some kind of help page (http://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1396795884), but that just tells you what to change it to. My problem is: where do I find $GLOBALS and how do I change that? And will that really fix everything?

Thanks! Hope I can fix this soon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the **Install Tool** > **All configuration** > **Toggle all** and find **trustedHostsPattern** (i.e. CTRL+F)

update the field, save the config, clear the cache.

If not sure which domain to set, just use a wildcard as descried there:

> To disable this check completely (not recommended because it is **insecure**) you can use ".*" as pattern.

P.S. In the LocalConfiguration.php it can be placed in the array:

```
<?php
return array(
    'SYS' => array(
        'compat_version' => '6.2',
        'encryptionKey' => 'foobar123',
        'sitename' => 'Foo Bar site',
        'trustedHostsPattern' => 'your_pattern_here',
        // other settings...
    ),
    // Other sections...
);
```

Comment: Using the wildcard is not recommended though, since this is security feature. PS: I added this answer/description to the exception page.

Comment: @pixelbrackets That's true, therefore __insecure__ is bold ;) good, that clarification went to Exception

Comment: How is this done via LocalConfiguration.php ? Yes I have to edit

    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['trustedHostsPattern']

but how is this done if you do not find it in the configuration?
Unfortunately I cannot access my backend via webbrowser.

Comment: @JohanesFrank - best option is setting it from `http://yourdomain.com/typo3/install` if won't help I'll paste content of LocalConfiguration __note: install tool doesn't check the pattern__

Comment: @biesior Thank you! Earlier what I meant by install tool, was the step-by-step installation process on `http://yourdomain.com/` itself and I wanted to find out how to configure the pattern directly in php (like you showed above). But before I did it in php, I found out, that to access the install tool I had to add `/typo3/install` to `http://yourdomain.com/`. That cleared everything up (also as to where "All configuration" was at all)